# Magento 2: How to get cart items and its stocks using custom API?

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, stock

I'm learning Magento 2 API. I need to create a custom API to get cart items and its stocks. I can see there is an API available to get cart items in Magento by default which is the below

```
GET V1/carts/mine/items
```

But I need to create a custom API to get the cart items. I'm not able to get the reference document to create it. Can anyone please help me how can I create custom API to get cart items and stocks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, like this ?

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/ManageCart.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

class ManageCart implements \VendorName\ModuleName\Api\ManageCartInterface
{ 
    public function getItems()
    {
        // you can also pass parameter
        // your code here
    }
}
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Api/ManageCartInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Api;

interface ManageCartInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @api
     * @param  int|string $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getItems();
}
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\ManageCartInterface" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ManageCart"/>
</config>
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/managecart/getitems" method="POST">
        <service class="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\ManageCartInterface" method="getItems"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Then you can use:

```
rest/V1/managecart/getitems
```